# encrypted youtube url is not working but working with '='

Tags: html, url, youtube

I have tried to use the encrypted url in my web page https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?autoplay%3D1  is not working.If I use '=' instead of %3D url is working well.what I did wrong in my url 
working url https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?autoplay=1 is working fine

Comment: Why can't you use the working one?

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode function of PHP in your script and put your url in the parameter. It will work.

```
urldecode("https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?autoplay%3D1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem .I solved it by using `urlencode` method from .net library for encoding and decoding via `urldecode` on the spot where i wanted to use it